# how do I make my player collide with the bottom of my platform

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to know how to make it so that when my player collides with the bottom of my platform it dose not just teleport to the top of my platform and it will make the player act like the platform bottom is there. I have tried using the same thing I did for the sides of my platform but changing it up to collide with the bottom of my platform but that did not work for me.

What is happeneing: https://gyazo.com/0854093887dfa2ada9e22da18d9ef751

My Platform class

```
class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.stone = pygame.image.load("stone.png")
        self.stone = pygame.transform.scale(self.stone,(self.stone.get_width()+28,self.stone.get_height()+28))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        platform_rect = self.stone.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        platform_rect.centerx += 2
        platform_rect.centery += 0
        window.blit(self.stone,platform_rect)
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
# The screen width and height
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
# The name of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

# Player class
class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        # Animation for player
        self.idle = [pygame.image.load("HRI1.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("HRI2.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("HRI3.png"),
                    pygame.image.load("HRI4.png"),]
                    
        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("HLI1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLI2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLI3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLI4.png")]
        
        self.walk = [pygame.image.load("HRW1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRW2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRW3.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRW4.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRW5.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRW6.png")]
        
        self.lwalk = [pygame.image.load("HLW1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLW2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLW3.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLW4.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLW5.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("HLW6.png")]
        
        self.jump = [pygame.image.load("HRJ1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRJ2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HRJ3.png")]

        self.ljump = [pygame.image.load("HLJ1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HLJ2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("HLJ3.png")]

        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "idlel"
        self.direction = "walk"
        self.direction = "lwalk"
        self.direction = "jump"
        self.direction = "ljump"
        
        self.speed =5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.next_frame_time = 0
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*3,image.get_width()*3))for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*3,image.get_width()*3))for image in self.idlel]
        self.walk = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*3,image.get_width()*3))for image in self.walk]
        self.lwalk = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*3,image.get_width()*3))for image in self.lwalk]
        self.jump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*3,image.get_width()*3))for image in self.jump]
        self.ljump = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*3,image.get_width()*3))for image in self.ljump]

    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
        if self.direction == "walk":
            image_list = self.walk
        if self.direction == "lwalk":
            image_list = self.lwalk
        if self.direction == "jump":
            image_list = self.jump
        if self.direction == "ljump":
            image_list = self.ljump
        # Is it time to show next frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if (time_now > self.next_frame_time):
            # time till the nect frame
            inter_time_delay = 1000 // self.fps
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_time_delay
            # Show the next frame
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
                self.anim_index = 0

        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 3
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)
    
            
        
        

# Platform class
class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.stone = pygame.image.load("stone.png")
        self.stone = pygame.transform.scale(self.stone,(self.stone.get_width()+28,self.stone.get_height()+28))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

        platform_rect = self.stone.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        platform_rect.centerx += 2
        platform_rect.centery += 0
        window.blit(self.stone,platform_rect)
        



        

# The color of **** hitbox
white = (255,255,255)

# Player size,cords, and hitbox color
playerman = Player(255,255,40,40,white)

# Platform size,cords,and hitbox color
platform1 = Platform(255,255,40,40,white)



# Platform list
platforms = [platform1]


#redrawing window so player and other stuff dose not make the screen a mess
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    playerman.draw()

    # making it so I do not have to draw every platform 1 by 1
    for Platform in  platforms:
        Platform.draw()

    
# Fps of the game
fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Runing the game/ the main loop
run = True
while run:
    # Making game run with fps
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False




        

    



   
        
    

    # telling what to do when we say the word 'key'
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    # Shortining playerman.x and playerman.y
    px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y



    # player 'A' movment
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
        px -= playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "lwalk"
        
    # player 'D' movment
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and playerman.x < 700 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        px += playerman.speed
        playerman.direction = "walk"

 
    # Playing idle animation
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "walk":
            playerman.direction = "idle"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "lwalk":
                playerman.direction = "idlel"

    
                    

    
    
    
    # player 'W' movment
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
        py -= playerman.speed

    # player 'S' movment
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and py < 500 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        py += playerman.speed


    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)


        
    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px


    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 0.5
        playerman.isJump = False
        

    # For player to get on top of platform
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
 

            # Making it so player wont fall out of the map 
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.JumpCount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Player jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
            playerman.fall = 0

        # What will happen when player jumps
    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:    
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10


    # redrawing the window
    redrawwindow()
    # updating the game
    pygame.display.update()
# quiting the game
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Would you like the player to hit his head on the bottom of the platform?

Comment: Yeah I want something like that, when it hits its head on the platform it starts falling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the player to bounce off the bottom edge of a platform while jumping, you must do so in case of `playerman.isJump` case. Test if the player collides with a platform.
Limit the player's position to the bottom of the platform (`playerman.y = platform.rect.bottom`) and stop jumping:

[image]

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    if not playerman.isJump:
        # [...]


        # What will happen when player jumps
    else:

        collideBottom = False
        for platform in platforms:
            if (playerman.get_rect().colliderect(platform.rect) and 
                playerman.y + playerman.height > platform.rect.bottom):
                
                collideBottom = True
                playerman.y = platform.rect.bottom
                break

        if not collideBottom and playerman.JumpCount >= 0:    
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    # redrawing the window
    redrawwindow()
```

Comment: So I'm having a small problem with the code, I get this invalid syntax error   every time I put it because I have another else statement at the bottom where it says ```else: if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:``` Do you know a way I can put both else statement's? https://gyazo.com/d6a0d66ccaee32ea9fef3d7ab203a4bf

Comment: @Windowman You don't need the extra  `else`. There is no `else` at all. The last part of the snippet in the answer is your `else` statement. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off `.isJump` once a collision occurs.

```
    # Player jumping
    if collide:
        playerman.isJump = False
        playerman.fall = 1
```

Also, it won't change anything, but that `.isJump` line is redundant.

```
if not playerman.isJump:  ##  a.k.a.  playerman.isJump == False
    playerman.y += playerman.fall
    playerman.fall += 0.5
    ##  playerman.isJump = False  <--  omit this line.  already False
```

---

**Edit:**
get rid of: `playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height`

Comment: Um, I have tried doing that but it did not really change anything, my player still keeps teleporting to the top of my block.

Comment: Heh, tired.  Not really "get rid of" but modify that line, so it only occurs when `playerman.y > platform.y`

Comment: So I have tried to update it by writing this line of code ``` if playerman.y > Platform.y: ``` under where the player is colliding with the platform and all I kept getting was glitches, I have tried to indent and unindent everything below it and that kept on giving with glitches like this:https://gyazo.com/4f4b9888a794a64d676a34f2ee607016

Comment: That's gonna depend on where their position is calculated from.  If it's calculated from bottom of sprite, add platform height to it.  `if playerman.y > Platform.y +Platform.height`  If it's calculated from the center, then divide that by half.  or you might have to add half of player height.  If you have it listed, I could look later, but getting dinner at the moment.

Comment: So, were do you want me to put the line of code?